# How can I properly configure the g++ include path with mingw64?

Tags: g++, mingw-w64, msys2, pacman-package-manager

I have installed msys2/mingw64 because I need the g++ compiler. Now, I want to compile some c++ oce which requires openblas. I have installed the package using `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-openblas`. However, compiling the code fails with

> fatal error: cblas.h: No such file or directory

Clearly, the include path does not contain the headers from openblas which are located at `C:\msys64\mings64\include\openblas`. This is easy to fix by passing `-I<include path>` as an additional argument to `g++`.

Now, I was wondering whether there is an automated way to include include files/headers of installed packages in the `g++` include path. The same problem also holds for libraries.

For example, `pacman` might be able to atomatically append these paths onto some environment variable which `g++` checks.

Comment: Did you see my answer below?  Please click the checkmark to accept it if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to get compilation and linking options for a library on MSYS2 and other Unix-like systems is to run this command:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs openblas
```

If you're just compiling, use `--cflags` by itself.

If you're just linking, use `--libs` by itself.

Here's an example Bash command you could use to compile a single-file program:

```
g++ foo.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs openblas) -o foo
```